# How would I write code for a UserForm that would allow user to select what row and/or column information could be added or deleted

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am an Advanced Emergency Medical Technician and am trying to make a user friendly excel workbook to keep track of our inventory on our Ambulance. I want to be able to allow users to add new items to a specific cell range or delete items from specific cell ranges by using a form only as some of the individuals I work with are no were savvy with excel. I would potentially a have sheet with items from every cupboard and at the bottom of every cupboard list have a button that would open a userform that would allow items within a specified named range to be deleted or new items to be added based on a user selecting something like place item above or below the row of an item they have selected. I am currently working from scratch on this one as I cant find anything to even start with.

Comment: Start small. It's very good that you have an idea for the whole solution, but take one step at a time. Your users won't know (or care) about rows or columns. They will only care that each "cupboard" has the items they expect. So set up a sheet with maybe ten rows and a few columns and then figure out how to make a userform interact with it. The data in the worksheet doesn't have to make sense (it can be fruits and vegetables for now). Google search for userforms and working with data, then come back and ask your specific questions.

Comment: So there is no question from your side? Then I have a suggestion, if you add items to a list on a sheet, do not add a button on the bottom, but at the top :). Furthermore, you could build the whole thing quite easily in an userform, just start and if you hit problems, you can ask over here. Right now, the question is too broad and likely to be closed. See [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Comment: Okay, Will Do!!! Might I add I want to keep it clean as I have a button that will be used at the end of doing daily vehicle and inventory checks that will be used to save the document and also export it as a PDF to to a specified folder to show all items that were checked for accountability purposes